# Wpf Custom ListBox with Rounded Border

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-style

I have extended `ListBox` control and wanted to give it rounded corner so I have applied styles as below and it works fine:

```
<control:MultiSelectionListBox SelectionMode="Extended" ItemsSource="{Binding Offerables,Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedItemsList="{Binding SelectedOfferables, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" MaxHeight="150">
    <control:MultiSelectionListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </control:MultiSelectionListBox.Resources>
</control:MultiSelectionListBox>
```

but I have too many  Listboxes and I don't wanted to add style in each and every control individually.

I wanted to define this style in app.xaml and wanted to reuse that design by name like `Style = "{StaticResource RoundedListBoxStyle}"`.

I have tried like below in app.xaml but with no luck

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="RoundedListBoxStyle">
    <Setter Property="Border"  Value="10"></Setter>
</Style>
```

> The member `Border` is not recognized or is not accessible.

Please guide me what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `Border` isn't a property of the `ListBox`, so unfortunately, this won't work.  The reason it works in your original `Style` is that it is actually targeting the `Border` *control* (not a property) within the visual tree of the `ListBox`.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Ok, So how should I define the same style in the app.xaml so that I can reuse it with other Key on other Listbox?

Comment: @BradleyUffner Thank you very much for your comment. It helped me to find correct answer and I posted the same. :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I managed to do that as [`Bradley Uffner`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner) mentioned in the comment `Border` is not the property of the `ListBox` and we cannot use it in style like that. I used `Style.Resource` and mentioned Style for Border elements as below:

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox" x:Key="RoundedListBoxStyle">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"></Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

and it worked. :)